# Best way to join two paths?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, windows

I'm trying to understand the best way to join two paths in Python. I'm able to get my expected result by using string concatenation, but I understand that is not the preferred way of working with paths. I'm trying to preserve the folder structure of a file, but move it to a new defined output directory.

For example -

```
import os

orig_file = r"F:\Media\Music\test_doc.txt"    
output_dir = r"D:\output_dir"

## preferred method, but unexpected result
new_file = os.path.join(output_dir, os.path.splitdrive(orig_file)[1])
print(new_file)
## new file = D:\Media\Music\test_doc.txt

## What I want
new_file = output_dir + os.path.splitdrive(orig_file)[1]
print(new_file)
## new file = D:\output_dir\Media\Music\test_doc.txt
```

As you can see, when I use `os.path.join()` it seems to discard the `"output_dir"` folder on the `D:` drive.

Comment: The `\output_dir` is discarded because you are trying to join two absolute paths. I believe you can use [`os.path.splitdrive`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html?highlight=path#os.path.splitdrive) to get the relative path from `orig_file` and then use that in `os.path.join`, but I don't have a Windows machine handy to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.4+, the best way to do it is via the more modern and object-oriented  [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module.

```
from pathlib import Path

orig_file = Path(r"F:\Media\Music\test_doc.txt")
output_dir = Path(r"D:\output_dir")
new_file = output_dir.joinpath(*orig_file.parts[1:])
print(f'{new_file=}')  # -> new_file=WindowsPath('D:/output_dir/Media/Music/test_doc.txt')
```